# search a text in another text with the characters in the same order

Tags: text-search

I would like to search for a text ('needle') if it exists within another text ('haystack') with the following two conditions:

1. all the characters of the 'needle' must be within the 'haystack' in the **same order**
2. there can be any and unlimited other characters between subsequent characters of the 'needle' within the 'haystack'

Examples:

- cde in abcde --> TRUE
- cde in ab-c-de --> TRUE
- cde in cabecd --> FALSE
- cde in c-d!a+b5ce --> TRUE
- cde in edc --> FALSE

Moreover 'cde' is not a constant string, instead a variable iterated over a list.

Any elegant solution in python or R or bash would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution in python:

```
re.match('.*'+'.*'.join(list(needle))+'.*',(haystack))
```

Answer (score 1):

I can propose you to use a dynamically generated regex like this:

```
/.*c.*d.*e.*/
```

Comment: sounds good but forgot to mention that 'cde' will be a variable, not a constant string.

Comment: And of course if you want it faster you can simply iterate through the characters of 'needle' comparing them with characters of the string with next after match.

Comment: That's 'dynamically generated' stands for, you should prepare regex before each search.

Comment: Pseudocode for the iteration(writing from a mobile phone): `pattern='cde' string='qqqcaaadzzzexxx' j=0 found = false for(i=0; i++; string.eol) { if (string[i]==pattern[j] ) { j++ next } if (j>pattern.eol) { found = true break } } `

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are your friend. 
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html